# How can I make a shape transparent in Java?

Tags: java, transparency, shapes

I want to make a shape transparant (the shape should be semi-opaque). How can I do this in Java? This is a part of my code:

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  super.paintComponent(g);
  g.setColor(Color.red);
  g.fillOval(40, 40, 40, 40);
}
```

Comment: what do you mean transparent? That you shouldn't see the shape, or that the shape should be semi-opaque?

Comment: Use a Color with alpha? Or set an AlphaComposite... or a Paint with transparency?

Comment: I mean semi-opaque. A paint with transparency.

Comment: Have you tried using a color that uses alpha? `new Color(255, 0, 0, 125);` (125 is the alpha)

Comment: Do not call super.paintComponent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The color you are currently using, `Color.RED`, does not use alpha, which is basically how transparent your color will be.

```
g.setColor(new Color(255, 0, 0, 125));
```

This will create a new color, using RGBA. The color I created uses 255 for red, 0 for blue and 0 for green. 125 is the alpha